# Question on definition of Schur polynomial from Fulton's Young Tableaux.

Tags: combinatorics, representation-theory, definition, integer-partitions, young-tableaux

In the following from Young Tableaux by Fulton, what happens if our Tableaux has numbers greater than $m$? Fulton gives an example with $m=6$, but according to his definition, we also have a monomial for $m=4$ and yet the numbers $1,2,3,4,5,6$ appear in the tableaux.

---

> Associated to each partition $\lambda$ and integer $m$ such that $\lambda$ has at most $m$ parts (rows), there is an important symmetric polynomial $s_\lambda(x_1,\dots,x_m)$ called a **Schur polynomial**. These polynomials can be defined quickly using tableaux. To any numbering $T$ of a Young diagram we have a monomial, denoted $x^T$, which is the product of the variables $x_i$ corresponding to the $i$'s that occur in $T$. For the tableau

> [image]

> this monomial is $x_1x_2^3x_3^3x_4^2x_5^4x_6^3$. Formally, $$x^T = \prod_{i=1}^m (x_i)^{\text{number of times $i$ occurs in $T$}}.$$

> The Schur polynomial $s_\lambda(x_1,\dots,x_m)$ is the sum $$s_\lambda(x_1,\dots,x_m)=\sum x^T$$ of all monomials coming from tableaux $T$ of shape $\lambda$ using the numbers from $1$ to $m$.

Comment: "...using the numbers from $1$ to $m$." In other words, for $m=4$ you would only sum over those column-strict $T$ with entries from $\{1,2,3,4\}$.

Comment: @Stephen I see. So, the monomial Fulton writes, $x_1x_2^3x_3^3x_4^2x_5^4x_6^3$, would not appear in the Schur polynomial of the partition $\lambda = (6,4,4,2)$?

Comment: Not if the number of variables of that Schur polynomial is less than $6$ (it doesn't make sense to talk about a *Schur polynomial* without specifying a number of variables, but you can talk about a *Schur function*---see e.g. Macdonald's book  *Symmetric functions and Hall polynomials* for the distinction).

Comment: @Stephen I thought for the partition $\lambda = (6,4,4,2)$, we have $m=4$, according to the definition. Isn't the Schur polynomial just a polynomial in the four variables $x_1, x_2, x_3, x_4$?

Comment: No: "Associated to each partition $\lambda$ *and integer $m$* such that $\lambda$ has at most $m$ parts..." (emphasis mine). In other words, you get a Schur polynomial from a pair $(\lambda,m)$. Taking the limit as $m$ goes to infinity in a suitable sense produces the Schur function, which *is* independent of the choice of $m$.

Comment: What's true about the Schur polynomials is that they are *stable* in the sense that if you specialize $x_{m+1}=0$ in the Schur polynomial for $(\lambda,m+1)$ you get the Schur polynomial for $(\lambda,m)$. This is, in the end, what allows you to define the *Schur functions* in the limit as $m \to \infty$.

Comment: Would it help if you saw a worked example of all this?  Perhaps it's worth posting an answer containing that and the rest of the info in the comments (this thread is a bit long already...)

Comment: @Stephen Thanks for the comments. I think I get it now. An example would be great though.